# React - Map function is not defined when using an external URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, axios

I am getting the usual error **.map is not function**. The error happens only when I am using external api url, at the same time when I open the url in the browser and copy the json data into to local file and call it via ajax it works just fine. I think there is an error in the JSON response. I couldn't figure it out.

Please check the code below. When I pass **url1** to axios am getting the error and when I pass **url2** to axios, data gets printed just fine.

```
class Products extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: []
    }
  }
  getProducts(){
    const url1="https://anagha.herokuapp.com/anagha-all-products/100";
    const url2 = "https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/sivadass/anagha-products";
    axios.get(url2)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          products : response.data
        }, function(){
          console.log(this.state.products)
        })
      })
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getProducts();
  }
  render(){
    var productsList = this.state.products.map(function(data) {
      return (
        <li>{data.title}</li>
      );
    });
    return(
        <ul>{productsList}</ul>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the [link](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqGx1Syr1NoXmXo9i7U) to working demo

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the json response, i parsed it using JSON.parse, then the error got cleared.

```
const url1="https://anagha.herokuapp.com/anagha-all-products/100";
axios.get(url1)
  .then(response => {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data);
    this.setState({
      products : parsedData
    }, function(){
      console.log(this.state.products)
    })
  })
```